# Bigtable test garbage collection in emulator & get most recent cell in a row

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm wanting to test the garbage collection in Bigtable emulator.
When I set the `GCRULES.maxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(1))`

My cells didn't deleted when I `readRowAsync`

My schema:
`user_id` as row_key,
`events` as column_name. When a new event belong to user_id appear. I create a new qualifer as `timestamp` of that events.

How can I get the top 5,10, etc. of the events from that row. I already try

```
filter(Filters.FILTERS.limit().cellsPerColumn(1)
```

but it still return all the cells

Example data:

```
event is a jsonObject contains("name", "timestamp", "other_params")

row_key: user_id_1

column_name: event
```

when A new event come in. I setCell base on these value

```
row_key: user_id_1

column_name: event

column_qualifier: event.timestamp

value: event.toString()
```

So I will have something like this

```
row_key     timestamp1   timestamp2    timestamp3  // sort from first to lastest

user_id_1    event_1     event_2       event_3
```

What I want is that to get only the lastest (Example: Limit(1) --> get only event_3)

Comment: Just to make sure that we're on the same page, can you share your sample data and expected output? @NhatHo

Comment: @CatherineO Thanks you for looking into my question. I have updated more details

Comment: Can you also share your reproducible code?